# MySQL index plan for high transaction table with many ID reference fields

Tags: mysql

The scenario: high transaction table containing 20 ID fields that link to other tables that has BOTH

- WRITES: lots of inserts, updates and deletes (via ONE process/connection)
- READS: dozens of queries running against it with variable selection criteria that may include anywhere from 1 to all 20 ID fields (via many processes/connections).

Given you can speed up loads by reducing the number of index's and speed up queries by making sure join/filter 
fields are index'd.  On this particular table dropping index's temporarily during load is not an option because
 queries may be run at the same time.

After MUCH reading on indexing plans, using compound index's, transactions and table locking I am thoroughly confused!

Questions:

1.) Generally speaking should the UPDATE problem be approached best through table locking since dropping indexes isn't an option (already using transaction)?

2.) With respect to indexing plan for reads and in consideration for the total number of ID fields and variable number of fields in play for each selection, is it best to maintain 20 separate indexs plus some compounds for the most common or implement some sort of hashing?

Upon reading other responses to similar threads I realize "general" answers are "generally" frowned upon.  However, I'm not sure how mocking up a table with 1 key plus 20 ID fields with sample code for delete, update and insert queries along with sample code 
for a dozen select queries with various combinations of the ID fields will illustrate the question any better than I have 
(open to alternate opinions though!).

Any guidance or references are appreciated (note I've already spent a lot of time at in the MYSQL docs).

Comment: Do you have any idea of the profile of the `SELECT` queries? Dozens could mean a number of things, are many of them similar or are they all distinct, if they are all distinct do you expect them to all be run in equal volume?

Comment: the READ queries are written is such a way that the user has some control over which criteria are employed (via stored proc, CASE, etc).  Yes, there are combinations used most frequently but my concern is temp tables whenever they pull for 10-12 conditions (edit) as this is a large table 2-3 million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for mysql 2-3 millions rows isn't that big. I have, with a suitable index plan, optimised 600,000,000+ row tables (~40GB) (although in that instance I knew and limited my SELECT range to make things easier to optimise, and that was pulling the large table as part of a 4 table join)

An InnoDB table with 20 columns of INT(11) and 1,000,000 rows exactly took up 106MB on my test server (with a single primary key on the first column). A second single column index adds 20MB.

My suggestion at this point would be to build your database structure you, populate it with a representative amount of data and the simulate the load you expect. Then think about the indexes you may want to add/remove and benchmark the performance differences.

If you then come across example queries you can't get your head around optimising ask on stackoverflow. It sounds like you have done your research though.

If your database is on a box with enough memory (and you are using InnoDB) you may want to look at tweaking the InnoDB buffer pool: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html

If you know that all updates are coming from a single process but all reads are from multiple sources you might find Master-Slave replication may help by spreading the read load across multiple servers. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-solutions-scaleout.html

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to ponder my dilemma and provide some advice.  From the sounds of it I'm nearing the end of what I can do programmatically to speed things up as I've spent a lot of time in your paragraph 3.  It's time to throw additional hardware at the problem (ie more memory and possibly replication).  Not that I won't continually refactor all the MySQL code based on new techniques learned here and elsewhere but it seems the days of cutting 10-20% off process times via architecture and code changes are about done!  Once again thanks, I will accept this answer.

Comment: If you find anything in the future that would be useful for other people to know, please post it as an answer here so that other people (including me) can learn from it :)

Comment: Right now I'm pondering the feasibility of combining several of the current ID reference fields into one table with all combinations.  For (loose) example if you had two fields "CountryID" referring to Country table and something else like "CustomerTypeID" referring to a dozen or so categories, I could combine those into one table that has all combinations of Country and Type.  Longer list but still relatively small for a Many:1 and eliminates an index.  Do this with three, four, etc fields and we'd eliminate several index'es on the transaction table.

Comment: Interesting idea, but would you not need indexes on both tables to relate them to gain any efficiency and then you are comparing an index of X + index of Y (assuming single filed index) with an index of X*Y. Again something I would have to benchmark to comment on with any authority.